# #css confusion about the spacing of top and bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, tailwind-css

Today I have encounterd a problem in css. I created a div named as main and its childrens is nav and box, in the box i have putted some content. when I fixed nav applying  its poistion in css as fixed and also scrolling is going good but in the top and the bottom of the main box a spacing or gap is appearing I don't know the reason why this happening. I'm beginner please help me.

I was expecting that the bottom and top gap not be there but after many tries it didn't fixed. Please help me to get out of the problem. I'm beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot better if you share your code. But basically, I suggest the code below:

```
.main{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you share your code? It would help a lot.

But basically you edit children like this.

```
#parent:first-child {
margin-top: 0px;
```

}.

This code is just example.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit difficult to give the exact solution as you haven't posted the code.
I suggest the following.

```
nav{
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
  left: 0;
 }
 /*use relative positioning for every element after nav with top: 0 and change to required px after seeing the result*/
/*Also the make margin-top,margin-bottom and padding 0*/

.box{
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding:0;
 }
```